# Opengl: Maximum shared memory size smaller than hardware specification

Tags: opengl, gpu, shared-memory, compute-shader

If I query the maximum compute shader shared memory size with:

```
GLint maximum_shared_mem_size;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_COMPUTE_SHARED_MEMORY_SIZE, &maximum_shared_mem_size);
```

I get 48KB as a result. However, according to this whitepaper:
https://www.nvidia.com/content/dam/en-zz/Solutions/design-visualization/technologies/turing-architecture/NVIDIA-Turing-Architecture-Whitepaper.pdf

on page 13, it is stated, that for my GPU (2080TI):

> The Turing L1 can be as large as 64 KB in size, combined with a 32 KB per SM shared memory allocation, or it can reduce to 32 KB, allowing 64 KB of allocation to be used for shared memory. Turing’s L2 cache capacity has also been increased.

So, I expect OpenGL to return 64KB for the maximum shared memory size.
Is this a wrong assumption? If so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the 48KB is the expected result, as documented in the [Turing Tuning Guide for CUDA](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/turing-tuning-guide/index.html#l1-cache):

> Turing allows a single thread block to address the full 64 KB of shared memory. To maintain architectural compatibility, static shared memory allocations remain limited to 48 KB, and an explicit opt-in is also required to enable dynamic allocations above this limit. See the CUDA C Programming Guide for details.

It seems that you can either take the default 48KB or use CUDA to gain control over the carveout configuration.